# Apache 2.4 VirtualHost Ubuntu allow access to only local network

Tags: networking, local, virtualhost, ubuntu-14.04, apache2.4

I want to modify my apache2.conf to only allow access devices that connect to my network(wifi) to my virtual host. I tried "Require ip 192.168.2.2/252" (My DHCP range is from 192.168.2.2 to 192.168.2.252) but apache 2.4 no longer accepts that.

Answer (score 0):

Apache 2.4 still [supports this](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/access.html).  Make sure the [mod_authz_host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html#requiredirectives) module is installed and turned on:

```
LoadModule mod_authz_host modules/mod_authz_host.so
```

(or similar path to the module)